# why different SQL JOIN return the same DB

Tags: postgresql

I training SQL on codewars. And there is task, where you need to use join

The one of answers was:

```
SELECT companies.*, products.*, companies.name AS company_name
FROM companies
inner join products ON companies.id=products.company_id;
```

And i think, that we take companies, then products(their columns) and get db
But i tried this code:

```
SELECT products.*, companies.name AS company_name
from products
inner join companies on company_id=companies.id;
```

And got the same result.
How work `JOIN`? Is it important, what we type after `FROM`? Is order in `SELECT` important?

Answer (score 1):

The inner join operation is *commutative*, like `+` or `*` in arithmetic. Joining tables like `A JOIN B` gives the same result as `B JOIN A`.

Database software like PostgreSQL may choose to join the tables in a different order than you specified them in your query. PostgreSQL includes a clever query optimizer that interprets your SQL query and executes it in the way it thinks will be most efficient.

Part of the beauty of SQL is that it is more or less *declarative*, so you write queries as an abstract description of the result you want, not the way it should be executed. There are exceptions to this—no programming language is a perfect implementation of the theory behind it—but that's the general principle.

For details on how PostgreSQL handles this, read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-joins.html